# How to get url without query param?

Tags: go

I want to get the request url from the client, but I don't want to get the param query from that url.

for example the client accesses:

`localhost:3000/posts?page=10`

but I just want to get:

`localhost:3000/posts`

I'm using golang with the echo framework, I tried using this:

```
...
func HomeHandler (ctx echo.Context) error {
     url := ctx.Request().URL.String()
     ...
}
...
```

but I get url with param query at once, so my question is how to get url without query param?

Comment: `ctx.Request()` just returns the standard `*http.Request`, there isn't anything specific to echo to get the path. The `URL` type is described in full in the docs: https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#URL

Comment: `u := ctx.Request().URL`
`u.RawQuery = ""`
`u.String()`

Comment: @Gavin Thank you very much, It worked

Comment: That will _modify the request_, which isn't generally a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print host and path for your situation. This way you don't change URL which is pointer (`*url.URL`):

```
    myUrl := ctx.Request().URL
    fmt.Println(parsed.Host + parsed.Path)
```